# Windows Mobile Connection Type

Tags: windows-mobile, wifi

I want to download some data if user is currently on a wifi connection but if user is connected using cellular data (e.g. 3G) I dont want to do anything to prevent data charges for the user.

In order to do this, I need to know current connection type. Is there any API that would give me this information? (This is a native application.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you will find [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/PeekPocket.aspx) article and sample-code useful.

Another option to verify WLAN-status would be by reading the following registry-value:

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\State\Hardware\Wifi**

at least according to [this](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/code-samples-tips/4727-wlan-state.html#post27135) post (which I guess you can easily adapt to native code). If WLAN is on, I guess you can safely let the user download data.

**Edit**: the values obtained seem to correspond to the following WLAN-status:

> 0 - powered off
>
> 1 or 5 - ready
>
> 11 or 15 - connecting
>
> 19 or 23 - connected

I am not 100% sure if when WLAN is connected, any other data-services such as 3G will not be used. Maybe this depends on the connection-settings. However, when I am using my device, I noted that if WLAN is connected, it "takes command". If you have the possibility, you should  verify this using different devices, perhaps with different operators.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It seems to work for me. Although it is not documented is State API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb154506.aspx).